# How to think of the Kodaira dimension of surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, surfaces

I am new to algebraic surface, so I have some questions maybe naive:

- How should I think of the Kodaira dimension of a surface?
- Why those with Kodaira dimension 2 are called "of general type"?
- What is the relation between surface being general type and canonical bundle being ample? I seem read from somewhere that ample canonical bundle implies general type. I tried to prove this, but I can only solve the special case of hypersurface. (Since the canonical bundle is $\mathcal O_S(d-4)$ and using the exact sequence $0\to \mathcal O(-d)\to \mathcal O \to \mathcal O_S\to 0$, twist $k(d-4)$ times and take cohomology. I don't know if this kind of argument apply to general case?)
- Why the surface with anti-ample canonical bundle should be think of opposite to of general type?

Sorry about put all these questions together :)

Comment: Question 1 and 4 are a bit vague.  3 is correct, but you have difficulty suggests I do not know your definition of general type. For 2, just think of hypersurfaces again. Any smooth hypersurface of degree at least 5 is general type, so `general' one is.

Comment: Maybe you should start with the case of smooth complex curves and work out the value of the Kodaira dimension in this case. This might help answering 4. As for 1, $\kappa$ captures the growth rates of the plurigenera.  In this sense, Kodaira dimension can be regarded as an analogue of  the dimension of $E^n$, where $n$ is the degree of the growth rate of the volumes of $r$-balls in $E^n$ as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: @Mohan My definition of general type is Kodaira dimension = 2

Comment: @MoisheCohen Why the plurigenera can be regarded as an analogue of the volume of $r$-balls?

Comment: I am sorry, I understand that, but what do you mean by Kodaira dimension?

Comment: @Mohan I mean the growth rates of $h^0(X, \omega^k)$

Comment: For ANY ample line bundle $L$, the growth rate of $h^0(L^k)$ is a polynomial of degree $=\dim X$ in $k$.

Comment: @Mohan Could you explain a little bit why? I can see it is enough to assume $L$ very ample.

Comment: If $L$ is ample, $L^n$ for all $n\gg 0$ is very ample.

Comment: @Mohan I mean enough to show if $L$ very ample then the growth rate of $h^0(X,\omega^k)=dim X$.